# css inherit from calc property seems to repeat calculation instead of inheriting the computed value

Tags: css

I'm having to classes that go like that

```
.c1{height:calc(100%-50px;}
.c2{height:inherit;}
```

then a bit of DOM that uses them:

```
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c2">
    foo
  </div>
<div>
```

so the problem is that if the div.c1 ends up with a heigth of let's said 400, I wished that the div.c2 would have the same height.

Turns out that div.c2 has height 350px. (using google chrome Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit) )

It quite looks like the calc was applied again.

I couldn't find any pointer on that.

Any idea ? is it the expected behavior ? or is it a glitch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're planning for `.c2` to take all parent space, then you should apply

```
.c2 {
  height: 100%
}
```

Otherwise, as you said - another calc would be applied. `Calc` is not some preprocessed value, but a formula, it does not replaces itself with actual value, but calculates it on runtime. Thus, inheriting `calc` means it would apply same formula on inherited element

Comment: ok thanks that is my solution too. but do you have some reference on calc formula being re-computed on inherit in the CSS specs ? I guess that should be mentionned somewhere ..

Comment: Sure. It might not be specified directly, but here is an CSS inheritance chapter, feel free to investigate https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html

Comment: well, that is my point :introduction : """The final value of a property is the result of a four-step calculation: the value is determined through specification (the "specified value"), then resolved into a value that is used for inheritance (the "computed value"), """ if I get this right it says that the value is computed, and then used for inheritance. If this does not apply to the calc function.. it ought to be more specific. Or am I getting it wrong ?

Comment: calc serves as function token (referred here https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#typedef-function-token ) and token is already a computed value (like a literal string). It inherits as is and does not produce any additional computation. Its like the same as if you specify "20em" for inheritance, only that you pass "calc(something)".